# Convert html string (json representation) into actual javascript object

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, json

I am printing some php data into a field on my page. The data is json_encoded by the backend.

Now i want to retrieve this information and turn it into a javascript object...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.trigger-info-change').click(function(){
        var rel = $(this).attr('rel');
        var td_id = 'info-'+rel;
        var data = $('#'+td_id).html();

        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

now data is correctly console logging my "object" like this:
`{"data":{"id":"1","data1":"1","data2":"2"},{"id":"2","data1":"3","data2":"4"}}`

Now the question  is how do i turn this **html** into a actual javascript object... I've tried to use **jQuery.parseHtml**, and some other things google advised but no luck... would i need a script or is there something like that out there?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want use Jquery:

```
var json = $.parseJSON(data)
```

Or

```
var obj = JSON.parse(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this better to print out JSON String in javascipt.

```
<script>
    var data = <?php echo $json ?>;
</script>
```

Which makes :

```
<script>
    var data = {"data":{"id":"1","data1":"1","data2":"2"},{"id":"2","data1":"3","data2":"4"}};
</script>
```

But if you insist on your way, use `JSON.parse(jsonString)`.

Comment: lol thanks for the reply, but i don't have the specific data object available to me, it is assigned and then read... so there is no "new" backend call to refresh the object in this way

Comment: I answered because you said "The data is json_encoded by the backend.". However ... ;) :D